# Powershell: Searching for Caps by regex

Tags: regex, powershell

So based on my testing using `[A-Z]` is worthless when looking for caps.

So here's the deal, I have a string with three characters.

I need to make sure that all three of those characters are capital letters.

I've searched stackoverflow and the web and tried this:

```
PS M:\> 'ADV' -match '[A-Z]{3}'
True

PS M:\> 'adv' -match '[A-Z]{3}'
True

PS M:\> 'A' -match '[a-z]'
True

PS M:\> 'adv' -match '[A-Z]'
True
```

This makes no sense to me! Why isn't the casing working?

Comment: Turn off the `i` flag.See http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got bitten by this myself recently.

Powershell will do a case insensitive match by default. You need to use `-cmatch` instead:

```
[PS] > 'A' -cmatch '[a-z]'
False
[PS] > 'adv' -cmatch '[A-Z]{3}'
False
```

Comment: What the actual F. Why would they program it that way? What is the point of using A-Za-z if they are all case insensitive searches?! *makes fist at MS*

Comment: Bizarre isn't it. Made even stranger by the existence of the `-imatch` operator which is explicitly for case insensitive matching...

Comment: Appreciate the quick response though! Thanks again!

Comment: PowerShell is fundamentally case-insensitive, unlike, say, .NET, which is why the following returns False: [RegEx]::Match( "ABCDEFG", "[a-z]+")

Answer (score 0):

Just to compliment arco444's answer I just wanted to address the constructive critisism by referencing the reasons for this behaviour. While it does seem counter intuative it is staying true to default PowerShell behaviour for operators.

If you look at [About_Comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) it states that:

> By default, **all** comparison operators are case-insensitive. To make a 
>       comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a "c".

`-Match` of course being one of those operators. It would appear to be redundant to use the prefix letter "i", given the default of case-insensitive, but depending on the situation this could make it clearer to the user the intention of the code.